# Как я могу запустить питон скрипт, находящийся в приложении Django, в виде фонового процесса?

Tags: python, django

Итак, суть вот в чем: у меня есть подобие сайта, на котором должны отображаться карточки со ссылками, заголовками и датами (Они должны были парситься с заданного сайта как раз в том файле, и помещаться в бд, созданные на основе моделей Django). Работоспособность самого кода я проверял через интерактивный режим, так что там, по идее, все рабочее. В нем еще используется асинхронный модуль asyncIO. Проблема возникла тогда, когда я попытался запустить его асинхронно, независимо от всех остальных файлов. Перерыл весь интернет, попробовал Huey, Dramatiq, APScheduler(В его документации я не смог разобраться) и даже пытался создать кастомную команду manage.py с запуском файла через os или runpy. Толку ноль. Celery не предлагать, пишу на Windows 10 и Python 3.9. Повезло же мне иметь винду :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @maestro , но как я смогу с помощью этого запустить файл из проекта Django? При запуске проекта, Django с ним никак не взаимодействует.

Comment: @micro_man думаю стоит уточнить вопрос, `запустить питон скрипт, находящийся в приложении Django, в виде фонового процесса?` это говорит о том что питонский скрип находится в проекте, ничего не мешает обернуть этот скрипт в фоновую задачу cron например

Comment: @maestro В общем, спасибо большое, вроде бы получилось)